# Mac 13. 2.1 - Need applescript to control the noise canceling of AirPods Pro

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, macos-ventura, airpods

For some reason I'm getting the error

> Can't get menu bar 1 of process SystemUIServer". Invalid index

Here is my code:

```
set AirPodsName to "Joris's Aripods Pro"
tell application "System Events"
tell application process "ControlCenter"
set volMenu to menu bar item "volume" of menu bar 1
tell volMenu to click
set btCheckbox to checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "ControlCenter" whose title contains AirPodsName
set btCheckboxValue to value of btCheckbox
tell btCheckbox to click
delay 0.1
set checkbox_anc to checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "ControlCenter" whose title contains "Noise Cancellation"
if exists checkbox_anc then
if value of checkbox_anc is 1 then
set checkbox_transparent to checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "ControlCenter" whose title contains "Transparency"
tell checkbox_transparent to click
else
tell checkbox_anc to click
end if
end if
tell volMenu to click
end tell
end tell
```

I'm expecting the code to Toggle between the 2 settings.